# setting default timestamp in simple_form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form-for

My simple_form_for has fields

```
<div><%= f.input :start_time %></div>
<div><%= f.input :end_time %></div>
```

start_time and end_time are my database columns in postgresql
by default when i open the forms it takes the current time as default as select it on options.
How to set the default time which is `02:14`(current time for start & end time) in the screensort to 00:00

UI looks like this
  [image]

database column 
  [image]

Comment: Why tag ruby-on-rails-3 and 4 both?

Comment: _"How to set the default time ... in the screensort to 00:00"_ - What should be the selected date?

Comment: What I meant by default is any value which I consider it to act as default, in my case I want 00:00 to be my default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably best do this in the controller method for new:

```
def new
  @model = Model.new
  @model.start_time = Time.now.beginning_of_day
  @model.end_time = Time.now.beginning_of_day
end
```

If I'm not mistaking, this should set the standard date to today, but at 00:00 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1) Set the actual attributes values at initialization, in controller action:

```
def new
  @event = Event.new(start_time: Time.now.beginning_of_day, end_time: Time.now.beginning_of_day)
end
```

2) If for some reason you don't want to alter the actual attributes, you can just set the values for inputs in view. Use with caution and sparingly.

```
<div><%= f.input :start_time, input_html: {value: (f.object.start_time || Time.now.beginning_of_day) } %></div>
<div><%= f.input :end_time, input_html: {value: (f.object.end_time || Time.now.beginning_of_day)} %></div>
```